# Apexchart: how to rotate labels

Tags: apexcharts

I have the following code:

```
labels: [**<dates dynamically populated here>**],                       
markers: {
    size: 3
},
```

As I am running out of space, how do I rotate date labels at the bottom of the chart 45 or 90 degrees?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Labels should rotate by default when there is no space, but if you want to have them always rotated (`rotateAlways` option) or change value you can do it in `xaxis` https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/#rotate

```
xaxis: {
  labels: {
    rotate: -45
  }
}
```